# How to solve a generating recurrence relation with varying constant?

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$a_n = R_1a_{n-2} + R_2a_{n-3} + R_3a_{n-4} + CD^{n-4} \quad\text{ for } n\ge 4$$

I'm  a little confused as to whether move the function around so that i solve the left hand side first for the equation below

$$a_n - (R_1 a_{n-2} + R_2 a_{n-3} + R_3 a_{n-4}) = CD^{n-4}$$

or treat the constant like the other three terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing

$$a_n - (R_1 a_{n-2} + R_2 a_{n-3} + R_3 a_{n-4}) = C~D^{n-4}$$

Is actually a very good idea.  You can also write

$$a_{n+1} - (R_1 a_{n-1} + R_2 a_{n-2} + R_3 a_{n-3}) = CD^{n-3} = DC~D^{n-4}$$

Can you see how to cancel out the $D^{n-4}$ now?

Comment: Ah yes it makes sense now. I didn't think of that. Thanks!